Maintaining Consistency Between Python (e.g. Polars) Functions and SQL (e.g. Redshift) UDFs
I'm working on a data engineering project that processes data from multiple sources using Polars in Python and Redshift as a data warehouse. I need a robust strategy for keeping Python Polars functions and user-defined functions (UDFs) which are intended to do the same thing consistent across both environments.
Consider this example (the functions are a lot longer in reality):
Python Polars Function:
def to_flatcase(sr: pl.Series): 
    sr = sr.str.to_lowercase().str.replace_all(r"[^a-z0-9]", "") 
    return sr

Corresponding Redshift SQL UDF:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_flatcase(title VARCHAR) 
RETURNS VARCHAR 
IMMUTABLE 
AS $$ 
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( 
        LOWER($1), 
        '[^a-z0-9]',  
        '' 
    ) 
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

My challenges are:

How can I ensure the Redshift UDF always matches the Python function logic going forward?
What's the best way to manage and version these functions in a repository given the first challenge?
Are there any tools or patterns that can help automate this synchronization?
What's the most maintainable approach to deploying these UDFs in Redshift?

I'm looking for strategies that minimize manual work and reduce the risk of inconsistencies between the two implementations.

"Do the same thing consistently across different environments", if that includes ingesting data using sql udf functions, then why? Ensuring similarity between two different implementations requires us to know what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

@NanomachinesSon Suppose I am ingesting data from 101 different sources, and this Redshift data is source #101. The repo I have 'inherited' reads and transforms the 100 sources with Polars, so it includes many ready made Polars-based Python functions. I am trying to read and transform this source #101 in a similar way, so one option is to do a simple "SELECT *" to read the full data into a Polars df, and then apply the same functions used for the other sources. But this way, I do not make use of the Redshift cluster which afaik would drastically speed up the end-to-end transformation logic

Thanks for clarifying, I believe Redshift has limited support for Python UDFs. Modules like numpy, pandas and scipy are some of them and  Polars isn't in the cards as of now. Your best bet could be to use Stored Procedures.

For taking X language and translating it to Y language you could use a compiler. The book Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools by  Alfred Aho and Jeffrey Ullman is where you'd want to start on this.
Using the lexical analysis part of the compiler, you could create a system where by as the tokens are made, you analyse them against a database. If the full length of the tokens match, call for that function. Otherwise continue with the other compiler steps.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
